# Whats this line mean? (system:call getfreediskex)

Tags: nsis

```
System::Call '${sysGetDiskFreeSpaceEx}(r0,.,,.r1)'
```

If i'm right, r0: directoryname, free bytes, number of bytes, number oof free bytes, but what actually means the r0,.,.,r1?
Thx for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${...} is a define so when you want to know how some things work then the first thing you should do is to find out what the define does: `!error "${sysGetDiskFreeSpaceEx}"` will print `!error: kernel32::GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(t, *l, *l, *l) i`

In the [System readme](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/System/System.html) you will find this nugget:

> PARAMS, RETURN and OPTIONS can be repeated many times in one Get/Call
>   line. When repeating, a lot can be omitted, and only what you wish to
>   change can be used. Type, source and/or destination can be omitted for
>   each parameter, even the return value. Options can be added or
>   removed. This allows you to define function prototypes and save on
>   some typing.

So ${sysGetDiskFreeSpaceEx} is a prototype that specifies the parameter count and types but it does not specify parameter source and destination.

What is the parameter syntax?

> The parameters list is separated by commas. Each parameter is combined
>   of three values: type, source and destination. Type can be an integer,
>   a string, etc. Source, which is the source of the parameter value, can
>   be a NSIS register ($0, $1, $INSTDIR), the NSIS stack, a concrete
>   value (5, "test", etc.) or nothing (null). Destination, which is the
>   destination of the parameter value after the call returns, can be a
>   NSIS register, the NSIS stack or nothing which means no output is
>   required. Either one of source or destination can also be a dot (`.')
>   if it is not needed.

We can now expand the entire call `!error 'System::Call "${sysGetDiskFreeSpaceEx}(r0,.,,.r1)"'` and this gives us `!error: System::Call 'kernel32::GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(t, *l, *l, *l) i(r0,.,,.r1)'`

If we merge the repeated parameter definitions we get `kernel32::GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(tr0, *l., *l, *l.r1)i`.

So parameter 1 is a string (LPTSTR on MSDN) with the source r0 (NSIS register $0).

Parameter 2 and 3 have no source and no destination, only parameter 2 uses a . (dot) but the end result is the same; no input and no output. The only important part here is *l so the system plugin knows how large the parameter is.

The final parameter is a pointer (*) to a 64 bit number (l) with no input (.) and we request the output to be stored in $1 (r1).

The system plugin calls the native Windows API so it is often useful to look at MSDN to see what it has to say [about the function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you are calling.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `$0`..`$9` and `$R0`..`$R9` are [NSIS registers](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#varother), the notation `r0` -> `r9` (resp. `R10`..`R19` or also `R0`..`R9`) is used by the System plugin to specify the `$0`..`$9` (resp. `$R0`..`$R9`) registers as a source and / or a destination with system API or other dll function calls.

Either one of source or destination can also be a dot (`.`) if it is not needed.

Look for the "Calling functions" and "Available sources and destinations" sections in the [system plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/System/System.html) documentation.